# Node.js + request json format

Tags: node.js, rest, spotify

I'm working with the spotify web api to build a Node.js app. One of the functions provided by the api allows you to play a specific track/album/playlist through the spotify player, here's the [Start/Resume a User's Playback documentation.](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/start-a-users-playback/)

However, when I send the put request, the song I chose doesn't start, it only continues playing the current song. I was hoping that it was my bad formatting of the json string to send, and not spotify's api not working?

Here's my code:

```
request({
    method: 'PUT',
    uri: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
    headers:{
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    data:{
        "context_uri": "spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX0s5kDXi1oC5",
        "offset": {
            "position": 0
        }       
    },                          
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    err = error;                            
});
```

I don't get any errors, as the api is doing it's job, I guess it just doesn't get the "context_uri" that I'm trying to give to it. I've also tried multiple different links for the context_uri that are valid.

So if you've looked at the documentation, I guess my question is should the context_uri be inside the "data" array, is that why it's not being seen?

Really appreciate the help, been trying to figure this out for days.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm:

`'context_uri': 'spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX0s5kDXi1oC5',
'offset': {
    'position': 0
}`

works as expected for me. It begins playing Justin Timberlake - My Love.

So the problem is elsewhere. Things to consider:

- The 'active' device hasn't recently been active / playing?
- You're not catching an exception somewhere else?